# Establish connectivity between PHP Laravel and SQL Server - using Windows authentication

Tags: php, sql, laravel, windows, authentication

I have an application developed in PHP 7.2 and SQL Server 2019. The application is hosted on IIS 10. I was able to establish a connection between the application and database using db's username and password. But now my client wants us to use windows authentication to access db. They gave us a service name and an instance name, nothing else.

The code used to test connection is

```````````
<?php

$serverName = "DEV1ECLD001A\FEB19M"; //serverName\instanceName

$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"ECLIPSE");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
try {
  if( $conn ) {
      echo  "Connection established.<br />";
  }else{
     //throw new Exception('Unable to connect');
    echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
       die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
  }
}catch(Exception $e) {
  echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
}

?>

``````````

In php.ini, added the lines below

fastcgi.impersonate = 0
mssql.secure_connection = On

In IIS sever,

Anonymous Authentication = Disabled
Windows Authentication = Enabled

My DB and UI are in 2 different servers and I am able to ping both and access the DB if username and password are given but not through windows auth.

While trying to connect, get this error below:

Connection Could not be established. Login failed for user prod/DEV1ECLD001A$

Am I overlooking something ? Kindly help to resolve.
```````````

Comment: you got any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need :

1. The service account must be in the Active Directory, and both server also in the same Domain (or approbated domain)
2. Use the [SQLSrv](https://pecl.php.net/package/sqlsrv) Extension ([PDO SQLSrv](https://pecl.php.net/package/pdo_sqlsrv)) for PHP and install [Microsoft ODBC Driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/connect/odbc/microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017).
3. Remove the user and password information from your PHP code. Keep it empty.
4. On IIS pool application advanced configuration, define identity to the service account (the password of the service account is need)
5. On IIS Website, check "use pool application identity" for Anonymous Authentication and enable it.
6. On the SQL Server, in connexion, add the service account from Active Directory and allow access on the database.
7. Keep the PHP.INI configuration same as "fastcgi.impersonate = 0"

Caution, if you use IIS Windows Authentication, the connected user need right to the database.

To check if the configuration is correct, the account displayed in the Windows Task manager for PHP-CGI.exe launched by IIS must be same as the account defined in the identity configuration of application pool.